# Polylang home url modification

Tags: php, wordpress, polylang

I’m developing a website where the home page is made from a custom template that I created. Once there, you can enter to the site and view the lastest posts.

The thing is that when I’m viewing the lastest posts and I want to change the site language, it takes me back to the landing page. I know that’s the correct behavior because that’s the home page.

But how can I modify it in order that the language switcher doesn’t take me to the landing page, but instead it only changes the language of the latest post?

Let’s say that the home site URL is:
http://example.com/en/home

And the lastest posts URL is:
http://example.com/en/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use parse_url and subtitute the current language there (make sure that is always there or you need to add it)

Comment: Ok. But where should I do it? I have only basic PHP abilities.

Answer (score 0):

You should try something it like this:

```
//fetch current URL
$current_url = explode ('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

//change language to 'de'
if ( strlen ( $current_url[1] ) == 2 ) $current_url[1] = 'de';

//new url (after /) will be
$new_url = implode('/', $current_url);
```

please note, there is only 'simple' check - if your first parameter in URL contains language - length of 2 chars. Only if this will be true, the language will be changed.
there is a lot of to do it safe and efficient, but it also depends on your project.

Comment: I'll try it. Thanks for your help!